# Why is there is a human in cave on my embark area?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've just embarked near a mountain, and on checking out my local area (3x3) I've noticed that there is a human in a small cave...

[image: Strange ramp...]

[image: MAN!]

[image: Desc]

Is this normal? I've never had this before! I've not even unpaused yet, I wonder what will happen? Strike the earth!

He comes up as a "Current Resident". What is that?!

**Update:** Things have taken a turn for the worse.

[image: FML]

[image: Help]

Gods be damned, I'm only a week in. We're doomed.

Comment: Just to update everybody, he is still alive after two years. I have yet to excavate him as I was stuck with a necromancer attack which claimed the lives of 15 dwarves. We're rebuilding, slowly.

Comment: That looks like a nice embark site, i hope you will keep me updated on the fate of your little cave dweller :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I no longer have this save. I wish I did because I remember it being an extremely fun embark. IIRC, I sealed him in and was going to capture him but never got to that point.

Comment: Oh sad to hear that, but thanks for answering

Comment: Of course. I'm just sad I no longer have this embark. Maybe one day I'll come across one like this, and make a great story out of it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Certain Nightcreatures (The randomly generated Night Trolls and Were-people), kobold clans, and semi-megabeasts claim caves during Legends mode, which have very real positions in the world.

Should you happen to accidentally embark on an occupied cave in Dwarf mode, you run into the scenario described above -- your starting 7 versus the "current resident(s)".

As you've already confirmed, when a single "civilized" race unit is the only occupant, it is because they are a Were-*something*, and will soon transform and cause havoc.

Vampires will not claim caves, Necromancers build towers (visible on embark select and usually non-embarkable), and Night Trolls self-identify with their current race, not whatever race the "Skulking Hag Groom" (etc.) originally was.

Comment: Thanks! I've covered the hole with a floor, and built a wall around it. In that tomb he shall reside, until such a time as we have a champion hammerdwarf strong enough to destroy him in the Grand Arena!

Comment: @Adam: Shouldn't you feed him somehow, lest he starves and your dwarves are bereft of such a fancy spectacle?

Comment: I wasn't sure whether he needed sustenance, maybe I should increase the priority of the prison and move him sooner. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @AdamKDean I wouldn't worry about it -- the only non-dwarf critters who can starve in Dwarf Mode right now are herbivores.

Answer (score 3):

According to the wiki, [Current Resident](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Current_resident) is normally applied to creatures that have killed a humanoid and thus have received a name. There's no mention of this applying to anything other than animals/monsters, so thiis might be a glitch, or a rare exception. On the other hand, there are reports of vampires as current residents, so what you may be looking at is a human vampire or werecreature that you just haven't identified as such... yet. Be careful.

(**Edit**: I didn't see your update until I was finished answering, so this seems to be confirmed...)

Comment: Thanks, we have entombed him, until such a time as he is required in the arena!